# How do I format titles that are smaller than \chapter title?

Tags: formatting

So I am writing a book on AWK, and the first \chapter is called "Line Spacing". In this chapter I a dozen of various line spacing methods, such as

```
1. Double-space a file.
2. Triple-space a file,
etc.
```

I am wondering how can I apply formatting to these methods so that each one of them looked like sub-title (smaller text, bold and numbered)?

Here is what I mean, so I have a \chapter called "Line Spacing" and then I wish "1. Double-space a file." to be also in bold but smaller font so it looks like a sub-title,

## Chapter 1: Line Spacing

... intro about what line spacing is ...

### 1. Double-space a file.

```
awk '1; { print "" }'
```

. . .

Answer (score 1):

In [your first question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-write-a-book-in-latex), you mentioned that you were going to take a look at the `memoir` document class.  If you are still working with this class, then see Chapeter 6 of [the Memoir manual](http://mirror.its.uidaho.edu/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) "Document divisions". This chapter explains how to customize the look of all 8 levels of Memoir document divisions from `\book` to `\subparagraph`.

Comment: @ Peteris Krumins. Yes there are templates althouth they may not be what you are searching for. They are called headstyles. Look at the manual at section 6.9 Are you sure that you don't mean \section{Double-space a file.}? If that is what you mean check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)