# What is the best class for writing a PhD thesis?

Tags: memoir, document-classes, thesis, classicthesis, books

What would you say: [book](https://ctan.org/pkg/book), [memoir](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), [classicthesis](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis)...? 
I want to read as much as I can on the class documentation before I start writing, so I avoid problems in the future, when I should be focussing on *content*, not *form*. 
Also, since I plan to read the documentations in advance, for those who've been through this before, please warn me about further important packages I should be aware of, so I can read their documentation in advance too.

*(I'm sorry for the subjective, discussional character of this question.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the available "documentclass" types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47964/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/.

Comment: It is probably a very opinion based question. But, that said. If the thesis is marked up properly, then the class used should not matter as it should all be down to configurations made in the preamble.

Comment: Obviously the `memoir` class. The documentation even provides an example for a thesis. (Please don't say that I am biased as being the original developer of `memoir`) ;-)

Comment: I had an edit to my comment and started within the 5 minute limit but finished outside it, so the edit was ignored. A bad decision on SE's part. I was trying to say that the main difficulty with theses is that the style referees have little idea about typography. They can usually be accomodated via packages changing the overall layout and line spacing. More difficult can be the title page. The `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`) does show code for an example thesis.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterWilson. I've taken a look at many packages' documentations and found that there is no gain to try to learn a class from studying a serious documentation before writing if not using the memoir class. And thanks for finding a way to answer this question, despite it being blocked for being opinion-based.